# SQL Server : the multi-part identifier could not be bound when using VIEW

Tags: sql

I have some tables I've joined together in a view and I execute the view when I want to pull the result. I want to apply a where clause to the view so that my results provided by the view are filtered, however when I do this I get the error The multi-part identifier could not be bound.

When take the SQL query from the view and run it as a standalone query with my where clause it runs fine, so I have a problem with applying the where clause to my view.

View

```
SELECT     
   dbo.Assets.assetid, dbo.Assets.assetcommonname, dbo.Assets.assetcode,   
   dbo.Assets.assetserial, dbo.Assets.assetinternallocation, dbo.Assets.assetmodel, 
   dbo.Assets.assetmake, dbo.Assets.assetmac, dbo.Assets.assetnotes, 
   dbo.AssetTypes.typename, dbo.Locations.locationame, dbo.Customers.customername, 
   dbo.Routes.routename, dbo.Locations.customerid
FROM         
   dbo.Assets 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.AssetTypes ON dbo.Assets.assettype = dbo.AssetTypes.typeid 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.Locations ON dbo.Assets.assetlocation = dbo.Locations.locationid 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.Customers ON dbo.Locations.customerid = dbo.Customers.customerid 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.Routes ON dbo.Locations.locationroute = dbo.Routes.routeid
```

How I execute the view with my where clause

```
select * from afViewassetlinked where (Locations.customerid = '1')
```

what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
select * from afViewassetlinked where (Locations.customerid = '1')
```

to

```
select * from afViewassetlinked where (customerid = '1')
```

The view `afViewassetlinked` is not the table `Locations`.